# Cannot find LoadModule for php5 in macOS HS

Tags: php, apache, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to activate php and apache on my Mac(running macOS v10.13.1). While trying to uncomment the LoadModule which would activate php I couldn't find option for php5[image]

SS for my httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$brew upgrade php56 --with-httpd
```

then activate

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.36_1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your suggested command
Error: invalid option: --with-httpd